# Class 'stripe\Stripe' not found in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I have installed stripe packege from this link : https://www.positronx.io/integrate-stripe-payment-gateway-in-laravel-application/

The form is displaying. But after entering the infos and clicking on pay now an error is appearing "class stripe/stripenot found".
I am using laravel 8.

**StripeController:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use stripe;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class StripeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * payment view
     */
    public function handleGet()
    {
        return view('frontend.pages.stripe');
    }
  
    /**
     * handling payment with POST
     */
    public function handlePost(Request $request)
    {
        Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        Stripe\Charge::create ([
                "amount" => 100 * 150,
                "currency" => "inr",
                "source" => $request->stripeToken,
                "description" => "Making test payment." 
        ]);
  
        Session::flash('success', 'Payment has been successfully processed.');
          
        return back();
    }
}
```

Do I need to do anything else ?

I have checked other solutions like including "require_once('/path/to/stripe-php/init.php')" in init.php

Here is my init.php file:

```
<?php

require_once('/path/to/stripe-php/init.php');

// File generated from our OpenAPI spec

// Stripe singleton
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Stripe.php';

// Utilities
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Util/CaseInsensitiveArray.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Util/LoggerInterface.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Util/DefaultLogger.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Util/RandomGenerator.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Util/RequestOptions.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Util/Set.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Util/Util.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Util/ObjectTypes.php';

// HttpClient
require __DIR__ . '/lib/HttpClient/ClientInterface.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/HttpClient/StreamingClientInterface.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/HttpClient/CurlClient.php';

// Exceptions
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/ExceptionInterface.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/ApiErrorException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/ApiConnectionException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/AuthenticationException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/BadMethodCallException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/CardException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/IdempotencyException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/InvalidArgumentException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/InvalidRequestException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/PermissionException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/RateLimitException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/SignatureVerificationException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/UnexpectedValueException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/UnknownApiErrorException.php';

// OAuth exceptions
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/OAuth/ExceptionInterface.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/OAuth/OAuthErrorException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/OAuth/InvalidClientException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/OAuth/InvalidGrantException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/OAuth/InvalidRequestException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/OAuth/InvalidScopeException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/OAuth/UnknownOAuthErrorException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/OAuth/UnsupportedGrantTypeException.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Exception/OAuth/UnsupportedResponseTypeException.php';

// API operations
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ApiOperations/All.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ApiOperations/Create.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ApiOperations/Delete.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ApiOperations/NestedResource.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ApiOperations/Request.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ApiOperations/Retrieve.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ApiOperations/Update.php';

// Plumbing
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ApiResponse.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/RequestTelemetry.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/StripeObject.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ApiRequestor.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ApiResource.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/SingletonApiResource.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/AbstractService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/AbstractServiceFactory.php';

// StripeClient
require __DIR__ . '/lib/BaseStripeClientInterface.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/StripeClientInterface.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/StripeStreamingClientInterface.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/BaseStripeClient.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/StripeClient.php';

// Stripe API Resources
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Account.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/AccountLink.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/AlipayAccount.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ApplePayDomain.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ApplicationFee.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ApplicationFeeRefund.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Balance.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/BalanceTransaction.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/BankAccount.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/BillingPortal/Configuration.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/BillingPortal/Session.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/BitcoinReceiver.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/BitcoinTransaction.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Capability.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Card.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Charge.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Checkout/Session.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Collection.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/CountrySpec.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Coupon.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/CreditNote.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/CreditNoteLineItem.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Customer.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/CustomerBalanceTransaction.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Discount.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Dispute.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/EphemeralKey.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ErrorObject.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Event.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ExchangeRate.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/File.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/FileLink.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Identity/VerificationReport.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Identity/VerificationSession.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Invoice.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/InvoiceItem.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/InvoiceLineItem.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Issuing/Authorization.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Issuing/Card.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Issuing/CardDetails.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Issuing/Cardholder.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Issuing/Dispute.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Issuing/Transaction.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/LineItem.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/LoginLink.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Mandate.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Order.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/OrderItem.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/OrderReturn.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/PaymentIntent.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/PaymentMethod.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Payout.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Person.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Plan.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Price.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Product.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/PromotionCode.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Quote.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Radar/EarlyFraudWarning.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Radar/ValueList.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Radar/ValueListItem.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Recipient.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/RecipientTransfer.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Refund.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Reporting/ReportRun.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Reporting/ReportType.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Review.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/SetupAttempt.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/SetupIntent.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Sigma/ScheduledQueryRun.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/SKU.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Source.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/SourceTransaction.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Subscription.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/SubscriptionItem.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/SubscriptionSchedule.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/TaxCode.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/TaxId.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/TaxRate.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Terminal/ConnectionToken.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Terminal/Location.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Terminal/Reader.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/ThreeDSecure.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Token.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Topup.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Transfer.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/TransferReversal.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/UsageRecord.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/UsageRecordSummary.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/WebhookEndpoint.php';

// Services
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/AccountService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/AccountLinkService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/ApplePayDomainService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/ApplicationFeeService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/BalanceService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/BalanceTransactionService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/BillingPortal/ConfigurationService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/BillingPortal/SessionService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/ChargeService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Checkout/SessionService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/CountrySpecService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/CouponService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/CreditNoteService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/CustomerService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/DisputeService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/EphemeralKeyService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/EventService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/ExchangeRateService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/FileService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/FileLinkService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Identity/VerificationReportService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Identity/VerificationSessionService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/InvoiceService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/InvoiceItemService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Issuing/AuthorizationService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Issuing/CardService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Issuing/CardholderService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Issuing/DisputeService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Issuing/TransactionService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/MandateService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/OrderService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/OrderReturnService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/PaymentIntentService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/PaymentMethodService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/PayoutService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/PlanService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/PriceService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/ProductService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/PromotionCodeService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/QuoteService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Radar/EarlyFraudWarningService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Radar/ValueListService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Radar/ValueListItemService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/RefundService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Reporting/ReportRunService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Reporting/ReportTypeService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/ReviewService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/SetupAttemptService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/SetupIntentService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Sigma/ScheduledQueryRunService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/SkuService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/SourceService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/SubscriptionService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/SubscriptionItemService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/SubscriptionScheduleService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/TaxCodeService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/TaxRateService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Terminal/ConnectionTokenService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Terminal/LocationService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Terminal/ReaderService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/TokenService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/TopupService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/TransferService.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/WebhookEndpointService.php';

// Service factories
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/CoreServiceFactory.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/BillingPortal/BillingPortalServiceFactory.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Checkout/CheckoutServiceFactory.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Identity/IdentityServiceFactory.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Issuing/IssuingServiceFactory.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Radar/RadarServiceFactory.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Reporting/ReportingServiceFactory.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Sigma/SigmaServiceFactory.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/Terminal/TerminalServiceFactory.php';

// OAuth
require __DIR__ . '/lib/OAuth.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/OAuthErrorObject.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Service/OAuthService.php';

// Webhooks
require __DIR__ . '/lib/Webhook.php';
require __DIR__ . '/lib/WebhookSignature.php';
```

Comment: You used `use stripe;` with lowercase. Perhaps changing it to `use Stripe;` will fix it?

Comment: No. Still same!!

Comment: You did install the package? `composer require stripe/stripe-php`? If so, maybe running `composer dump-autoload` might help.

Comment: Wooow composer dump-autoload worked like magic. Never thought this simple thing will work. Thanks. How to mark your comment as answer ?

Comment: If you're using Laravel (which uses Composer), why are you manually including all these files?

Comment: No. I didnt add them manually. I checked other answers. They said to include "require_once('/path/to/stripe-php/init.php');" inside init.php. But didnt work. composer dump-autoload made it to work.

Comment: @TanjibRubyat I have added it as an answer, you can flag that as answered if you want. You can also consider deleting your question as this problem has probably hit everyone at some point and has been asked more than once :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try checking the capitalization of your import. You should rename `use stripe;` to `use Stripe;`.

If you did install the package using `composer require stripe/stripe-php`, try running `composer dump-autoload`. This will regenerate the list of all classes that need to be included in your project. That will probably pick up the newly installed package.

Comment: In my case, I had to close and re-open my editor (VS Code) as well.